# React Native: How to add two Actions to a button ?

Tags: react-native, reactive-programming, react-native-ios, react-native-router-flux, react-android

I have a small problem. I want to pass down two Actions to a Button, but I can't seem to figure it out. I am using the react-native-router-flux library. I tried something like this, but It doesn't really work.

If anyone could help that would be awesome. Thanks !

```js
<Button 
  onPress={Actions.Main1 && Actions.Tab2} 
  style={{ width: 90, height: 90 }} >
      <Text>Show</Text>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onPress` prop takes a function, and only a function. There is no syntax for automatically combining two funtions in Javascript. You need to create a new function which executes both actions.

```
<Button 
  onPress={(e) => {
      Actions.Main1(e);
      Actions.Tab2(e);
  }} 
  style={{ width: 90, height: 90 }} >
      <Text>Show</Text>
</Button>
```

Some notes:

1. I passed the event parameter into both of the actions, since passing just one of the functions (i.e. `onPress={Actions.Main1}`) itself would pass this parameter as well. This may not be necessary in your case.
2. The slight issue with this code is that creates a new function every time the `render` function of this component is called. It's not terrible, but also not ideal. Consider that in the future. I include that optimization in this post because a) we don't see the rest of the implementation of the component, b) I think this question was rudimentary enough for us to just worry about the main concept.

Comment: I am really grateful for the answer. I tried it but for some reason I get the Error: react-native-router-flux missed route data for key=Main1, every time I press my button. If I make it with one Action it works fine. I am currently looking into it, maybe it's something stupid. I  started React a week ago, so it could get a bit overwhelming..

Comment: I understand. Quite possibly we need more information about your class here. Is the component calling this an ES6 class, or do you use `React.createClass`? Additionally, where/how are the `Actions` functions declared?